# EF 6 dependency on System.Data.Entity

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, entity-framework-6

With EF6, my understanding is that all EF related classes have been moved into EntityFramework.dll. I see following code that is using DbContext class

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class MyDataModel : DbContext
    {
        public MyDataModel ()
            : base("name=MyDataModel ")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
```

This DbContext class is defined in System.Data.Entity but project itself does not have any reference to System.Data.Entity.dll in the references section. Two questions

1. Does it mean that EF still have a dependency on System.Data.Entity
2. Why there is no reference to System.Data.Entity.dll in this case

Answer (score 2):

System.Data.Entity is part of EF6. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn223258(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Thanks but can you add reference in English language? Unfortunately I am not good in any other language except English :)

Comment: Sorry, [here in English](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223258(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You will not need a reference to System.Data.Entity (it is included in the EntityFramework.dll).

However, make sure you have EF 6.x installed correctly.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906.aspx

- Enter:  Install-Package EntityFramework
- Before hitting entry key, if your solution contains more than one project, make sure your project is select Default Project dropdown at top of Package Manager Console.

Once installed, you will note two new references:

- EntityFramework.dll
- EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Plus the packages file will contain

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

And your app.config file will contain

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```